# Is it possible to define a scene in a separate class?

Tags: java, javafx

This may have been asked before but i was not able to find an answer. Im working on a JavaFX app that contains a lot of scenes and a lot of animation. Currently I'm having different Animationtimers and different Scenes all defined inside the start() function, inside the main class that extends Application. However the code gets very messy and long.

Is there a way in which you can define all of these things in a separate Java class, and then simply do something like `primaryStage.setScene(MyScene.getScene)` - MyScene being the java class that has all your scene code.

Something like this:

```
public class TestScene {

    private Group root = new Group();
    Scene test = new Scene(root);
    Button button = new Button("test");
    root.getChildren.add(button);

}
```

And actually having that code be a scene that you can just import and set on primaryStage.

Edit: I have no idea why this was so difficult for my mind, as Bertijn said I obviously just need to use a constructer. For whatever reason I forgot that, and so I obviously couldent perform a root.getChildren.add(button), outside a function of some sort.

If anybody else struggles with this here is the super simple solution:

Class containing our scene:

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class OurScene {
    public Scene getScene() {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.GREEN);
        Button button = new Button("Hello world!");
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        return scene;
    }
}
```

And then to add it to primaryStage:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        OurScene ourScene = new OurScene();
        primaryStage.setScene(ourScene.getScene());
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please state your use-case (not your assumed solution :) and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates where/how you are stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a class called `Scenes`. In the constructor, created all your scenes, you can give them an id if you want. In your main class, just create an instance of this class `Scenes scenes = new Scenes();`. The scenes get created. Then you can access them by creating a `getScene(String id)` method.

Hope I understand your question correctly, and if this doesn't answer it, feel free to get back to me!

Comment: My problem with that is that java class will not be extending Application and therefor i cannot do things as usual. Say i wanted to create a scene that contains a button with the label text. I would simply in the start() function say Group root = new Group(); Scene scene = new Scene(); Button button ("Hello world"); root.getChildren.add(button); primaryStage.setScene(scene). But all of that code would be inside the start function, and it gets messy when you have 10 scenes. Therefor i would love to be able to do something similar but inside another class.

Comment: @Behar Can't you just import the Scenes class in your main class, without having it to extend the Application class?

Comment: No that wont work, if it does not extend application you cannot use roots and stuff, as far as i can tell atleast. I just tried if. Perhaps you could give me a coding example if you know how to do it?

Comment: @Behar you can create and fill scenes whereever you want .. just try it :) But then, why would you want to do it? And why do you want 10 or more scenes?

Comment: Im creating a game, which has a start menu, highscores scene, the actual game scene, etc.